# How do I query an XML service using YQL?

Tags: xml, web-services, rest, yql

I'm using the [YQL Console](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/) to experiment with querying a REST XML web-service.

I found a simple public service to play with.

http://www.thomas-bayer.com/sqlrest/CUSTOMER/-151612345/

returns

```
<CUSTOMER xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <ID>-151612345</ID>
  <FIRSTNAME>Deepthi</FIRSTNAME>
  <LASTNAME>Deep</LASTNAME>
  <STREET>440 - 20th Ave.</STREET>
  <CITY>Los Angeles</CITY>
</CUSTOMER>
```

If I use the query:

```
select * 
from xml 
where url='http://www.thomas-bayer.com/sqlrest/CUSTOMER/-151612345/'
```

I get this XML returned. However, if I try to restrict to data to a single element, e.g.:

```
select * 
from xml 
where url='http://www.thomas-bayer.com/sqlrest/CUSTOMER/-151612345/' 
  and xpath='//LASTNAME'
```

no results are returned.

What am I doing wrong?

[Click here to display the YQL console with the query loaded.](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/#h=select%20%2a%20from%20xml%20where%20url%3D%27http%3A//www.thomas-bayer.com/sqlrest/CUSTOMER/-151612345/%27%20and%20xpath%3D%27//LASTNAME%27)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct key for filtering the results as you want is not `xpath`, instead it is `itemPath`.

```
SELECT *
FROM xml
WHERE url='http://www.thomas-bayer.com/sqlrest/CUSTOMER/-151612345/'
  AND itemPath='//LASTNAME'
```

<sup>([Try this query in the YQL console](http://y.ahoo.it/0Ee0C))</sup>

You can see the keys for a given table by issuing the query `desc <tablename>`.

```
desc xml
```

<sup>([Try this query in the YQL console](http://y.ahoo.it/WP57VQ))</sup>

In the case of the `xml` table, the `itemPath` can either be an XPath expression or an E4X dotted path.